# java generics and SuppressWarnings

Tags: java, generics, warnings, static-methods

I have classes

```
abstract class A {
    //....
}

class B extends A {
    //....
}

class C extends A {
    //....
}
```

Then I have

```
interface Maker<T extends A> {
    SomeClass make(T obj);
}
```

implementations for Maker class

```
class MakerForB implements Maker<B> { /*... */ }
class MakerForC implements Maker<C> { /*... */ }
```

and class Factory with one static method

```
class Factory {
    public static SomeClass makeSomeClass(A obj) {
        Maker maker = null;
        if(obj instanceof B) maker = new MakerForB();
        /* ... */
        return maker.make(obj);
    }
}
```

In that case I get warning that Maker is a raw type, when I declare Maker that way

```
Maker<?> maker = null;
```

I get exception (make is not applicable for the arguments A) on

```
return maker.make(obj);
```

What is the best way to get rid of these warnings **without** using

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of all generics on the `Maker` - you don't need it:

```
interface Maker {
    SomeClass make(A obj);
}

class MakerForB implements Maker {
    SomeClass make(A obj);
}
```

Or if you still want to use it, go with an unsafe cast or with the `SuppressWarnings`.

To understand why you get an error if your try defining:

```
Maker<? extends A> maker = null;
```

Imagine the case when you (by accident) get `maker = new MakerForC()`, and try applying it to `B`.

Comment: Ok, i think I go with suppressWarnings then cause a really want to avoid casting

Answer (score -2):

If I understand your question right, I think you could try replacing

```
class Factory {
    public static SomeClass makeSomeClass(A obj) {
        Maker maker = null;
        if(obj instanceof B) maker = new MakerForB();
        /* ... */
        return maker.make(obj);
    }
}
```

by

```
class Factory<S extends A> {
    public static SomeClass makeSomeClass(S obj) {
        Maker<S> maker = null;
        if(obj instanceof B) maker = new MakerForB();
        /* ... */
        return maker.make(obj);
    }
}
```

didn't test it, so if you get other errors now, please let me know.

Comment: this doesn't work. the method is static. if the type S is defined on the method, it still doesn't work.

Comment: In that case I get cannot make static reference to the non-static type S

Comment: ah yes, I see...
So maybe a solution is to implement the singleton pattern in stead of using static methods?